# Group parameters in Dialogflow

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

I'm working on a shopping list. I found a nice edge case which makes me crazy if you add one element together with a count and unit everything is fine. E.g. *"one bottle water"*, however it becomes very complicated when you say *"I want one apple and one bottle water."* There is just one unit in that case *bottle*.

How can I find out to which *group* the bottle belongs to?

Just for testing keep also this in mind *"I need salt, one cheesecake and two bottles of wine."*

Comment: Can you update your question to include examples of how you're designing the Intents in Dialogflow to try and capture the multiple groups?

Comment: I am not really sure how I should show that. Basically I just would use that sentences above as samples (I'm using a different language, but that does not matter). Then I would tag the interesting words as `@sys.number` for the count, and two custom entities for the units and the products. Should I mention that each field "is list"?

Comment: well, show the screenshot of the intent.

Comment: @Prisoner sorry for the delay here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/968z8kwlieukkxa/Screenshot%202018-11-07%2008.28.24.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, however I suggest not to use it. Theoretically it works fine, but in practice the natural language understanding is messing that up. You will get product names split in two fields and such things. E.g. Coca Cola and Pepsi Cola will likely been split into two values which are not helpful. It is also unlikely that your users will use units and counts anyway.

The solution is quiet simple check the indices of the words. Take the raw input and split it by each product name, if the part before the product name contains the "next" unit or count then you find out that this values belong together. Keep in mind that dialogflow might will give you some counts in words like "one", you need to check for that too.